# How to place element on Flowpanel in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am using ui binder to place elements on a GWT page but I am not able to place them correctly.As per my knowledge element in flow panel should appear in a horizontal line but they are appearing in a vertical line.

```
<g:FlowPanel>
  <g:Label ui:field="searchLabel" text="{labels.searchFor}"> </g:Label>
  <g:ListBox ui:field="searchListBox"></g:ListBox>
</g:FlowPanel>
<g:SimplePanel addStyleNames="{cres.style.textAlignCenter}">
  <g:Button ui:field="searchButton" text="{clabels.search}"/>
</g:SimplePanel>
```

Comment: FlowPanel is translated in a div element. You can use HorizontalPanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FlowPanel` is just a (widget) wrapper around a simple `div` element. All the child widget will *naturally flow* as per the standard HTML behavior (i.e., block and inline elements are displayed as such).

On the contrary the `Label` widget is not a wrapper of an HTML `label` element. Again, is a `div`, so everything stacks up in your `FlowPanel`.

You can:

- use an `InlineLabel` instead of a `Label` (will render as a `span` element);
- use a `float` style on the `Label` or any other CSS trick to make two `div`s aligned horizontally;
- use an `HTMLPanel` instead of a `FlowPanel` (they will behave the same), and lay out elements using also HTML for simple things like labels (i.e., mix and match HTML and Widgets inside it);
- use an `HorizontalPanel` instead of a `FlowPanel` (but this will render as a `table` element, be warned).

Answer (score 1):

Flow Panel working is some what strange. will  not arrange all the Elements in the flow.Only for some Elements it will work as you expected.For example Buttons.
In case of  block level elements will be same as Vertical Panel.For example if you are inserting two Horizontal Panels in  a Flow Panel it is same as  insering in Vertical Panel.
To achieve side by side arrangement you have to use CSS Float style.

Answer (score 0):

The label is surrounded by a `<div>`-tag. Without a css style, every `<div>`-tag has a line break.

Use:

```
searchLabel.getElement().getStyle().setFloat(Style.Float.LEFT);
```

to avoid the line break.